# SQL rounding last zeros

Tags: database-design, number-formatting

I need to store the exact value of a decimal:

For example `0.00500` and `0.0050`.

If I use `decimal (10, 5)`, I receive `0.00500` every time. If I enter `0.0050`, I still get `0.00500`

Comment: You MUST use string datatype, not number. Or you may add a field which stores source precision, and round the value to it during select.

Comment: You mean varchar?

Comment: Char, binary, varchar or varbinary - that's your choice.

Comment: @user191366: The actual data type would depend on a number of things, including the product you are using, but yes, `varchar` is one of the options. But if you want to work with the data as numbers rather than strings, then there's no simple solution. Perhaps you could elaborate on the underlying problem you are trying to solve (*why* you want `0.00500` and `0.0050` to be treated differently by the database even though you store them in the same column).

Comment: What is your server?

Comment: Do you have a particular database management system (e.g. PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Server, Firebird, MySQL, etc.) in mind? If that's the case, [add](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/249276/edit) the corresponding tag(s).

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any *great* answers here.

I don't know of any commercial database systems that store trailing zeros after the decimal, as these are considered insignificant to meaning.

However, in scientific measurement, those zeros *can* be significant, and knowing if something is 0.05 or 0.050000 is a major difference in precision of measurement.

One option is to store your number as a string/varchar value. This gets icky because now you have to do extra work to protect someone from saving a non-numeric value there.  That's more work for you, and more work for the database every time a value is stored. You can add a check constraint and use `TRY_CONVERT()` but in my opinion, this is trying to cram a numeric peg into a string hole, and that isn't quite right from a data model perspective.

A better option might be to simply store your measurement/value in a decimal column, then also store the precision in a separate integer column. When you insert your decimal value of `0.050000`, you store `6` as your precision in a separate column. Then, when you consume the data later, your query will return a decimal value of `0.05`, and precision `6` ... Which is exactly the data you need to know the original value is `0.050000`. Here, there is still some extra work on maintaining your precision column, and it will need to be considered carefully on display (everywhere, including reporting), and in the case of maintaining scientific measurement you'll need to determine significant digits manually when performing math operations.

Answer (score 0):

You used to have to go through all sorts of hoops to do this and this sort of manipulation can be an error-prone process.

What I recommend is a `COMPUTED` (aka `GENERATED`) column which are a Godsend for this sort of requirement.

You haven't specified your server, so I have two fiddles (1 for [`MySQL 8`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8b2c83502761d8fe2d12c30a76ea133), 1 for [`PostgreSQL 12 beta`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=33559f33385e9aa80183c41803dad244) - release due shortly). Analogous syntax should be available for all the major servers.

I presume that you want this for some sort of reporting functionality, but I have included storing it both as a string (`TEXT`/`VARCHAR()`) and as a `FLOAT`.

Create your table MySQL example used here (see discussion):

```
CREATE TABLE num
(
  it_1 DECIMAL (10, 5),
  it_2 VARCHAR(25) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM it_1)) VIRTUAL, -- memory
  it_3 FLOAT       AS (CAST(it_1 AS FLOAT)) STORED -- on disk
);
```

And then run a simple `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO num (it_1) VALUES (0.005);
```

And then a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM num;
```

Result:

```
   it_1      it_2    it_3
0.00500     0.005   0.005  -- Note the extra two digits in the 
                           -- DECIMAL column, not present in the INSERT
```

Note that `MySQL` is more flexible regarding its definitions than `PostgreSQL`. You can set the storage type to either `VIRTUAL` (i.e. the calculation is performed on the fly) or `STORED` (i.e. on disk) - `PostgreSQL` only allows `STORED` for the moment(*). Furthermore, `MySQL` also allows you to simply use `AS` instead of `GENERATED ALWAYS AS`.

The relevant documentation is available [`here`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) (MySQL) and [`here`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) (PostgreSQL).
(*) This is one of the few areas where `MySQL` is superior to `PostgreSQL`.